# How to delete Documents-Full Reindex Solr using Apache Nifi PutSolrRecord Processor

Tags: solr, lucene, apache-nifi, solrcloud

Here is the situation:Am new to Apache Nifi. I have built a quick worflow in Apache Nifi to Index Data from Oracle database to Solr Standard Core Instance.
I have 2 Processors:
1-QueryDatabaseTablle-Gets data from Oracle Database
2-PutSolrRecord- Indexes the records into Solr.

These works fine but my problem is everytime I run the workflow, the Documents get duplicated- meaning the previous records are not deleted and new plus existing records are indexed- growing the number of the documents. basically duplicating the solr documents

Question: Like in Solr Data import Handler(DIH)-Now deprecated, is there a way I can configure The PutSolrRecord processor in Nifi to first delete all preindexed recordsin solr index before indexing new ones+Existing documents in the Solr index? I dont want to do incremental indexing, but delete everything and insert new records/documents in the index each time I run the nifi flow..

Is there a PutsolrRecord processor property for this delete configuration?

[the Nifi flow](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HrsAf.png)

Comment: Rather than trying to update the core index, create a new index on the side with the new data and when done swap out the old core with the new one.

Comment: Collection aliases is the way to do that if you're looking for how Solr supports doing it with zero downtime.

Comment: @edjm, thank you for the Idea, How do I do that on the go without manually intervening. Thes servers are accessed in realtime without the possibilty to down them update and swap.

Comment: @MatsLindh , thank ypu for your suggestion. This how ever leads in the direction of solar Cloud and Zookeeper.. for ther reasons in our environment we cant implement solar cloud not just yet. That means collection allias wont wont in this scenario. Am looking for alternative to DIH. that used to to update the index on the fly even when being queried. Any other idea??

Comment: Can you post an image of the flow you do have that deals with the flow for your Solr logic approach?  The idea I'm thinking is that you instead of directly calling the CORE index, you use NiFi InvokeHTTP calls to create a tempCORE, your NiFi flow would be interacting with the tempCORE to populate it with all new information. While this is going on your primary CORE remains in place so there is 0 impact to the user. Once the tempCORE is populated, optimize it, then SWAP the tempCORE with the CORE all by using the InvokeHTTP calls and solr actions SWAP and optimize=true calls. Hard to explain.

Comment: @edjm, I added the Nifi flow image to the Question thread

Comment: @edjm I see your idea, but would that be a bit complicated, given that currently the data is updated every 30 min(Ofcourse using the DIH) but since its deprecated, and not support in Future solr releases, I was try the NIFi way, until I run into the Problem decribed on the question. I wonder what other people use to injest data into real time solr cores?--local, not the cloud cores.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem by configuring ExecuteStreamcommand Nifi Processor to execute a https culr command that is then passed on to solr to delete all documents, then the next PutSolrRecord that will then reindex the documents.
I have multiple cores runnings that way i plan to mitagate the access downtime while one core is reidexing.